# Turn SCTP support on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: erlang, ubuntu-22.04, sctp

I am building a SCTP supporting application with Erlang and I stumbled upon some problems likely related to my machine (I tried the same code on another machine and it works just fine). I am using Ubuntu 22.04. When I try to gen_sctp:open(...) it returns: "{error,eprotonosupport}" which after some research turns out to be " The protocol type or the specified protocol is not supported within this domain.".
I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libsctp-dev lksctp-tools
sctp_darn -H 0 -P 2500 -l
sctp_darn -H 0 -P 2600 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 2500 -s
```

And it seems to work just fine.
After:

```
lynis audit system | grep sctp
```

It returns:

```
* Determine if protocol 'sctp' is really needed on this system [NETW-3200]
```

So it seems to be enabled. What am I missing? (port is 3868)

Edit:
The port is open. I tried with ufw and iptables for all protocols and solely for sctp. It did't work.

Edit 2:
So after setting up 2 VM's Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 everything seems to work as expected. I guess I have messed something up with my system.